# What does a temperature failure look like in the syslog?

Tags: ubuntu, physical-environment

I have a ubuntu server that I suspect failed due to overheating. I'm doing a post-mortem and I'm not exactly sure what to look for to confirm my hunch.

Any thoughts on what logged information would indicate a failure from overheating?

Comment: Kernel panic?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not have `sensord` from the `lm-sensors` package running, you probably would never know for sure. Maybe you could try looking at side-channel data like SMART attribute logging done by `smartd` (smartmontools) - it logs attribute changes to syslog and may contain disk temperature - which in turn would allow an educated guess about the system's temperature.

Comment: I did not have `sensord` running (I do now, thanks) Is there anything else that would show up in the syslog that might indicate a temp problem?

Comment: The lack of shutdown logs would be a good indication too.